# Visual Studio - Prevent stopping debugging from closing Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Under visual studio if you run a web project by pressing the <kbd>Go</kbd> button on the Debugging toolbar, then stop it by pressing the <kbd>Stop</kbd> button on the debugging toolbar, Internet Explorer is opened and closed by the IDE.

Is there a way to prevent the IDE from closing Internet Explorer when stopping debugging? I want to do this to allow myself to refer to the content of the pages in IE while editing my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `Detach All` option from the `Debug` menu.

Comment: Is this option available in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 13):

I find that running it once without debugging is the way to go. First time, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> (starts web without debugging). This opens your browser and starts the web server for you.

Later on, you could debug and it'll use your same browser window, but hitting stop won't cause the window to close.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it:
Get the URL for your project, you may have to run it once to get the port number and to start up the webserver (if you are using the built in one).

Then open a browser session, and put your URL in.

IF you want/need to debug, then just do an attach to process under the debug menu, I have setup a shortcut/macro to do this step for me.

Comment: On task bar the web server also could be seen when debug stopped. Right click it and click to "Open in Web Browser".