# When I click the "stop" debugger button, the developer web server also stops!

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Does this happen to any one of you?  It is driving me crazy:

On every other machine I develop on, when I click the "stop" button for the debugger in Visual Studio, the Developer Web Server continues to run. And I can still browse my web application.

Suddenly one day, on one of the machines I use for development, it no longer behaves this way.   Now when I click stop, the Developer Web Server also stops.

Does anyone know what causes this?  Did i accidentally flip some setting I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to configure your local site to use IIS; that would allow you to easily switch between using the debugger and not using it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way around this is to run without debugging (CTRL + F5). This leaves the web server up and running. If you hit debug after that it will do the debugging bit on a separete instance of the web server, leaving the original instance up and running too.

See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281034/visual-studio-prevent-stopping-debugging-from-closing-internet-explorer) on SO

Answer (score 1):

This solutions was helped for me

http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/iis-express-immediately-shutting-down.html

You need:

1. Go to "Options" (Service/Options)
2. Find "Debugging" options and select "Edit and Continue"
3. Uncheck "Enable Edit and Continue" checkbox

Hope it will useful

Comment: Add more details to your solution not only a link to the solution

Comment: Richard, prefer inline content over link-only answers.