# Visual Studio Stop Debugging on IE Close - WebSite?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, internet-explorer

Would like to know if there is a setting anywhere which causes debugging to automatically stop when IE closes, and also if there is a way for this to work the other way around and IE to close if debugging stops.

I know that this works when the project type I'm working on is a 'Web Application', I'd like to know if the same functionality exists when working on a 'Web Site'

Thanks all.

Comment: Duplicate - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281034/visual-studio-prevent-stopping-debugging-from-closing-internet-explorer

Comment: @Prutswonder: I don't think it is a duplicate of that question. This question refers to a "web site" whereas that question refers to a "web application", and the person asking the question made that clarification.

Comment: Yep not a duplicate, web applications that solutuion works, not on web sites.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the default behavior of visual studio.  i.e. , if you create a default asp.net website, and F5, then after you quit IE, VS automaticallly stops debugging.  it doesn't work for aother browsers since these browsers don't have corresponding interface with VS.