# Visual studio removes cookies when I stop debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, internet-explorer-9

Our web applications authentication works with a cookie so that the  user authentication doesn't depend on a session that can expire. This works great except for when I'm debugging.
Visual studio seems to delete all the "localhost" cookies when I stop debugging. This means I have to log in again every time I start debugging.

Can I somehow prevent Visual Studio from deleting the cookie when I stop debugging?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't happen for me. Are you sure the Cookie is persistent and you have set its expiration date (if you are setting the authentication cookie manually then you need to specify expiration for the cookie as well as the `AuthenticationTicket`)?

Comment: Have you tried hosting the application via IIS instead of the development server?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail explaining how you stop and start debugging? I am asking because it is possible to stop debugging, change code, recompile and then reattach to the process that the browser is running under.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses! I do set the expiration date and the cookie isn't expired. It's like the debugger cleans up after himselve. I've also tried using IIS instead but the result is the same.

Comment: @ShaiCohen: I'm start and stop debugging in the debugging toolbar (the stop and play icon). I haven't changed any settings in visual studio so far, and IE9 is the default browser for visual studio

Comment: If you do not close the browser after you stop the debugger, you can reattach to the process like this (from the menu): click Tools --> Attach to Process (or Ctrl+Alt+P) --> look for w3wp.exe process and attach to it.

Comment: The debugger closes the browser. When I use chrome to debug my application the debugger doesn't delete the cookies and the browser isn't closed, but then I can't debug my javascript in Visual studio...

Comment: Look here for how to prevent the browser window from closing: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281034/visual-studio-prevent-stopping-debugging-from-closing-internet-explorer). HTH

Comment: I tried the solution but when I detach all processes, the debugger stops as well...

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. Ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also had your problem and, by disabling the "Stop debugger..." option, my problem was solved. I am using Visual Studio 2019.

[image]