# Stopping debugging in Visual Studio fails to close browser

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

I have the opposite problem as this thread:

[Visual Studio - Prevent stopping debugging from closing Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281034/visual-studio-prevent-stopping-debugging-from-closing-internet-explorer)

In both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 whenever I debug my Web Projects, hitting [Stop Debugging] (or [Shift-F5]) still stops debugging, but no longer closes the browser (IE10).  If I don't stay on my toes, this leads to many many browser windows being open, and eventually my machine starts grinding to a stop.

It's not a show-stopper, but it's bothersome nonetheless.

John

Answer (score 0):

When you stop debug, you just stop VS debugger, but IIS is running yet and you can continue browse your site.